# Opencart2.x: Sort products by their subcategory

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Found many solutions for sorting by alphabet, price, etc.

But I need to sort the products according to the order of the subcategories.

For example, I have a parent category "Computer", which contains the subcategories "Laptops", "Tablet", "Accessories".
How to make products from the subcategories "Laptops", then "Tablet", "Accessories" appear first.

**Now:**

> 1 Laptops | 1 Tablet | 1 Accessories
>
> 2 Laptops | 2 Tablet | 2 Accessories
>
> 3 Laptops | 3 Tablet | 3 Accessories

**I need to:**

> 1 Laptops | 2 Laptops | 3 Laptops
>
> 1 Tablet | 2 Tablet | 3 Tablet
>
> 1 Accessories | 2 Accessories | 3 Accessories

Thank.